# Update subscription Braintree and prorateCharges Error ID already taken

Tags: updates, subscription, braintree

Hey everyone so I am trying to update a monthly subscription to another monthly subscription in Braintree and prorate the charges. After reading their documentation I am stumped on how to do this effectively. When I go to update the subscription I get the following error message: 'ID has already been taken.'

```
router.put("/update-subscription", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log("hit route");
    if (!res.locals.user) {
      throw { status: 403, message: "Not logged in." };
    } else {
      const { subscriptionId, selectedPlanName } = req.body;
      const oldSubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
      const selectedPlanId = selectedPlanName.replace(/\s/g, "_");
      const userId = res.locals.user.id;
      const [[userData]] = await database.query("call getUserByUserId(?)", [
        userId
      ]);
      const { braintreeId } = userData;
      const { paymentMethods } = await gateway.customer.find("" + braintreeId);
      const { token } = paymentMethods.find(p => p.default);
      console.log("oldSubscriptionId", oldSubscriptionId);
      console.log("selectedPlanId", selectedPlanId);
      const subUpdateResponse = await gateway.subscription.update(
        oldSubscriptionId,
        {
          id: selectedPlanId,
          paymentMethodToken: token,
          options: {
            prorateCharges: true
          }
        }
      );
      console.log("subUpdateResponse", subUpdateResponse);
      if (subUpdateResponse.success) {
        res.send("Successfully updated plan");
      } else {
        throw { message: "An error occurred." };
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Heres the Log

```
subUpdateResponse ErrorResponse {
  errors:
   ValidationErrorsCollection {
     validationErrors: {},
     errorCollections: { subscription: [Object] } },
  params:
   { id: 'SILVER_MONTHLY',
     paymentMethodToken: 'krs2p5',
     options: { prorateCharges: 'true' } },
  message: 'ID has already been taken.',
  success: false }
{ message: 'An error occurred.' }
```

I understand that the 'SILVER_MONTHLY' ID is already used I mean I am trying to update from one subscription to the other obviously the one I am trying to update to has already been used. Again all I am trying to do is update from the subscription the user is already on to the subscription the user picked to update to. Any help here would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, I recommend contacting [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com)</sub>

You are passing the plan ID in the incorrect parameter. The [`id`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/node#id) parameter can be used for a new subscription ID that you'd like to have. To update to a different plan, you'll need to pass a [`planId`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/node#plan_id) parameter, which represents the plan you'd like to update them to.

I also noticed you are passing a [`paymentMethodToken`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/node#payment_method_token) parameter. This is to be used only if you're updating the payment method token. If that's what you intended, carry on! Otherwise, you do not need to pass this parameter in your update request.

As an example, if you wanted to update the plan and keep the same payment method token, your request may look something like this:

```
const subUpdateResponse = await gateway.subscription.update(
  oldSubscriptionId,
  {
    planId: selectedPlanId,
    options: {
      prorateCharges: true
    }
  }
);
```